# how to join two field from different table in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have two different table in phpmyadmin. One is `tbl_user` and another is `donate`.

Now I want to take the column `donation_date` from `tbl_user` and all columns from the `donate` table. I want to join one column (`donation_date`) from `tbl_user` table and all cloumns from `donate` table, but dont know how to write the query.

In the below code I just wrote the query of `donate` table so how can I join the `donation_date` from the `tbl_user`.

Here is my details of two tables in phpmyadmin.

`tbl_user` table :

[image: tbl_user table]

[image: tbl_user output]

`donate` table:

[image: donate table]

[image: donate output]

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mypro_bms','root','');
$statement = $db->prepare(
    "insert into donate(passport_ic,blood_group,blood_bag,)
     values(:passport_ic, :blood_group, :blood_bag)"
);
```

Comment: Would you please show us sample data for tables `tbl_user` and `donate`, and the corresponding expected output?

Comment: i already edited my post there yon check the output

Answer (score 1):

> I want to take the column `donation_date` from `tbl_user` and all columns from the `donate` table.

Are you looking for... a simple `JOIN` between tables `tbl_user` and `donate`?

From your schema images, it looks like column `passport_IPC` can be used to join the tables. Then you can choose which columns to return in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT u.donation_date, d.*
FROM tbl_user u
INNER JOIN donate d ON d.passport_IPC = u.passport_IPC
```

Comment: the thing is i want to display a donor record. to do this i need all information from donate table and donation_date from tbl_user table.

Comment: @MimHsan: ok, well this is what the query does. Can you please test it against your data and let me know if it works properly for you?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Passport_IC is the common column between the two tables?

You really should use be using numeric, indexed columns.  But since you have a small DB, this should work:

```
SELECT d.*, u.donation_date
FROM donate d
INNER JOIN tbl_user u ON u.Passport_IC = d.Passport_IC
```

EDIT: You should give your a tbl_user table a primary key as well.  Look into database normalization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you want to take the column donation_date from tbl_user so you will select just the column nedded `tbl_user.donation_date` ans use the following alias `donation_date` and to get all columns from the donate table you can use this trick `donate.*`, it gets all column

```
SELECT 
    donate.* , tbl_user.donation_date as donation_date 
FROM 
    tbl_user
JOIN 
    donate ON donate.passport_IPC = tbl_user.passport_IPC
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Thank you , you are right , i will add some explanations right now